# DataAdapter - Using multiple adapters?

Tags: vb.net, dataset

If I need to pull 3 tables into my application and I am using .NET SQLAdapter, Would it better to have 1 SQLAdapter for EACH dataset or is it ok to use 1 SQLAdapter for all three datasets?

Comment: "better" is opinion based or at least situational: how is the data related? *is* the data related?  how is the app structured? is there a DAL?  You may not need 3 DataSets though since one can hold many tables

Comment: So the question should be... What if I want to grab data from a table(Table1) and all related rows from a related table(Table2) into one dataset and one sqldataadpter.. ex. Table1 is related to Table2 by Table1.t1_id=Tabled2.t1_id.

Comment: DataAdapters and DataTables are very very powerful and flexible objects and can much more than just fill DS/DTs.  If the tables are related, you can build those relationships so the DB Provider objects can enforce things like cascading deletes.  It still depends on how the app is structured, but generally I would use as few as I needed and maybe have persistent CommandBuilder objects to reconfig the DAs as needed,